# Copying files in the background

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, client-server

When I connect my client to my server, the client begins copying some dll files to the server.
When this occurs, the form gets stuck until the copying is complete (there are some large files).

I wish to make this copy run in the background, since I want the user to be able to continue interacting with the form (open some browse dialog boxes etc.)
I will make sure that the copying is complete.

I guess threads will help here, but I'm new to threads and I'm also not sure that is the way to do it.

Here is the code for copying the dll files:

```
   private bool copyDllsToServer()
    {
        //string targetPath = @"\\" + remoteIpAddress + "\\" + userName + batchRunPath;
        string targetPath = "Z:\\nBatcher\\" + userName + batchRunPath;
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        else
        {
            Directory.Delete(targetPath, true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFilesToCopy.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listOfPathToCopy[i].CompareTo(omekPath + shadersPath) == 0)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath + "Shaders"))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath + "Shaders");
                if (!File.Exists(targetPath + "Shaders\\" + listOfFilesToCopy[i]))
                    File.Copy(listOfPathToCopy[i] + listOfFilesToCopy[i], targetPath + "Shaders\\" + listOfFilesToCopy[i], true);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!File.Exists(targetPath + listOfFilesToCopy[i]))
                    File.Copy(listOfPathToCopy[i] + listOfFilesToCopy[i], targetPath + listOfFilesToCopy[i], true);
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `BackgroundWorker` for this (basically wraps a threadpool thread up in a nice component to drop on your form and makes marshalling to the UI thread a little easier). You can also use the events to report progress on the copy function if you'd like.

See here for a tutorial on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

One caution I will make though. Only do intense file operations in a single thread because you could run into disk I/O problems using concurrent threading.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.DoWork += (s1,e1) => copyDllsToServer();

        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response, we got back to work only today. by writing `(s,e)` I guess you mean those two: `object sender, EventArgs e` right? Well I'm kinda new to c# and still not familiar with all of its syntaxes, so this one is new to me. By writing what you did, I get the following error on both `sender` and `e`: `A local variable named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sender', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`. What change should I do?

Comment: I gave you ready solution. you should copy/paste *my* code. i compiled and run it before posted here.. (*although* you must ensure that the names arent used anywhere before in the method you place this code - so I changed to s1 e1 just in case you already have s or e [NOT sender etc])